# No interface method isAsyncStarted() error running wiremock android tests on a Meizu device

Tags: android, wiremock, android-instrumentation, meizu

I have an Android app which performs a network request. I'm using wiremock for instrumentation tests and retrofit in the app.

The request is mocked like this:

```
        stubFor(
            get(urlMatching("/hello/world"))
                .willReturn(
                    aResponse()
                        .withStatus(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                        .withBody(expectedServerResponse)
                )
        )
```

The retrofit interface:

```
interface HelloWorldService {
    @GET("/hello/world")
    fun getHelloWorld(): Call<ResponseBody>
}
```

The application code which performs the request:

```
        val helloWorldService =
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_BASE_URL))
                .client((application as MyApplication).createRetrofitHttpClient())
                .build()
                .create(HelloWorldService::class.java)
        helloWorldService.getHelloWorld().enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                textView.text = if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    response.body()?.string()
                } else {
                    response.message()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                textView.text = t.message
            }
        })
```

When the mocked response's content length is large (over 256 characters), and the test is run on a Meizu Note 5, wiremock finds the response and looks like it's about to send the `200` response, as I see this in the logcat log:

```
Matched response definition:
{
  "status" : 200,
  "body" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "headers" : {
    "Content-Type" : "text/plain"
  }
}

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: [text/plain]
Matched-Stub-Id: [a45b21c9-95f6-45fa-a7c3-acf473485fb6]
```

However, the app actually receives an `500` error code, with this message in the error response:

```
No interface method isAsyncStarted()Z in class Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest; or its super classes (declaration of 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest' appears in /system/framework/meizu2_jcifs.jar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that wiremock and meizu both embed `javax.servlet` classes, but different (incompatible) versions.  One workaround for this is to relocate (change the package names) of the `javax.servlet` classes embedded by wiremock.

Instead of including wiremock like this:

```
androidTestImplementation "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.23.2"
```

Use the gradle shadow plugin and use the shadowed jar instead:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.1.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.ShadowPlugin
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar
android {
    dependencies {
        shadow "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.23.2"
        androidTestImplementation files("$buildDir/libs/shadow.jar")
    }
}

 tasks.configureEach { theTask ->
    def taskName = theTask.name.toString()
    if (taskName =~ /generate.*Sources/) {
        theTask.dependsOn tasks.named("shadowJar")
    }
}

 tasks.register("shadowJar", ShadowJar) {
    baseName = 'shadow'
    configurations = [project.configurations.shadow]
    relocate ('javax.servlet', 'com.example.wiremockexample.javax.servlet'){}
}
```

A full sample project explaining this problem in more detail is here: https://github.com/libon/WiremockMeizuError

And a PR on the project implements this answer: https://github.com/libon/WiremockMeizuError/pull/1